# How to model Nernst equation for numeric solution?

Tags: batteries, equation

I want to write a program (this is not programming question!!) that numerically solves voltage across virtual battery-resistor circuit over time. But sometimes explanations is too overcomplicated, not using simple terms. This approach favors short length, but slowers understanding alot (requires years practicing math, to get clear vision of "what is going on", just seeing math notation). Let me please explain on example that I can understand.

[image]

For a `RC` cirtuit, its very easy. When solving ODE numerically you have some bunch of changing values, measured at fixed snapshots of time `t`. To know voltage you may do `V(t) = V(t-1) + dV(t-1)*dT`. That is a main calculus loop of a solution program. You know `V(t-1)`, `dT` is fixed. And `dV(t) = -V(t)/RC`. So far so good, [this resource](https://www.intmath.com/differential-equations/6-rc-circuits.php) is a bad explanation example. Because solver does not require exp, it arises from solution. It does not require integral, so on.. No simple formula `dv/dt = ...`. At least they have graph (reversed, for charging) from where you may get simple intuition: [image]

Now I want to simulate chemical battery (accumulator), google said I need [Nernst equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation). But wiki guys again start with `Ox`,  arrows `->`, kind of some other fancy symbols, that should occasionally get to `Red`?.. Oh, I was just about writing a sim program within 5 minutes, but they dont get answer. All that I want is "to simulate it in digital ODE solver do *this equation*, where parameters are..". So, finally, my question is - can you help me to rephrase in simple words? Or how to calculate `dV(t)=?` for a battery?

PS. A battery starts at t=0, with known V(0) = V0, conneted to resistance R again, so on.. and i want kind of simple model that would draw me something like [image]

Comment: What I think you're missing is that the expression you highlight si not a mathematical equation but chemistry notation, to illustrate the reduction reaction, not something you calculate.

Comment: Do you care about chemistry type, cell voltage? capacity Ah, ESR , C rate? total charge Q. Which parameters would you like?  A simple model uses Double-Layer Effect capacitor with two RC slopes above a minimum cell voltage and a leaky diode in series for cutoff

Comment: @BrianDrummond from a programmer's perspective, everything is a calculation, split to simple operation like addition, multiplication, so on. And every process can be *estimated* via simulation. So if  you would develop something like NI Multisim, or circuit lab.. how would you calculate voltage changes at fixed timesteps? It definetely can be written without learning chemistry and its notation, only if you get proper equation that couples with real experiment results. All you need is just to feel correct relations in formulas

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Not really, if some parameter could be omitted, they should be, for sake of calc speed. All that it need, to resemble discharge graphs, provided at the end of question, then I can consider model close enough. Do you know where to read some simple formulas? Or maybe can has one by hand?

Comment: No . But if you can specify the parameters I listed , the I can design an equivalent circuit that can be simulated easier that creating formulae.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Oh, great idea. Lets take typical liion 18650, 2600mah. Initially, it is at 4.2V and then resistor R connected across terminals. goal is to achieve graphs, similar to classic li ion discharge graph under some constant(within session) current. temperature is ignored (i guess it affects internal resistance, but not really needed)

Comment: It was a little harder than I thought.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxZ5A.png  http://tinyurl.com/y5vme63v  I've never seen anyone simulate these curves but I put in a 4 position switch with a charger and load. Won't generate your curves . http://tinyurl.com/y5vme63v

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 good, but.. that does not account battery death drop, when you discharge it past 3V and it starts to drop very fast and degenerates chemically. in my model i want to simulate that too. not the capacity reduction, but a rapid voltage drop

Comment: You may add all the complexity you like with rise in ESR as Ah C values fall .  That requires memory which is not reversible unless you are lucky to catch it early.  What's the point of this simulation?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Point.. I want to write sim, where agents goal is to charge its battery. Agents have cap C, each energy goes to/from it, it has zero ESR, but its short living and leaky. Agent's workaruound is to use it's rather huge batt for long-term storage. Agents goal is to keep its batt full and healthy, so I need a model for a batt.. That's just one piece that i miss from whole picture. Just another matrix sim.

Comment: But what's the point? Demonstration MTBF ? Cost of human error?  efficacy of leaky chargers?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 same as in food, what is the point of food? can there be any another living creatures, even in sim, that would exhibit same behavioural patterns that human would do, in a search for food? how would agents establish will for seeking for food instead of just short term sugar (capacitor, capable of running agent's actuator for less then a minute in favour for batt that cant deliver instant power but can let operate for orders of magnitude more time)? This is just a hobbyst project, studying some narrow aspect of robotics general AI (if it is even possible)

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 but there is difference. you may choose whenever food is fast sugar, or slow (like typical breakfast slow calories), imagine when you may be fat or thin, just at desire. what would you choose and when? so that's goal of sim. that's inaccessible to humans, where these mechanisms are controlled by internal processes, but not consciousness.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 *you have a cap at X volts and batt at Y Ah of charge. your goal is to decide, wherether you should charge batt from cap, or charge cap from batt?* Applications is.. real world, you may have everything connected to a cap. What is an algorithm, that should run behind this?) It is possible to decide fuzzy thing with neural network, that would learn to solve that or another task, by having good batt model

Comment: Use fuzzy logic to learn the exact characteristics by some tests seems to be a better way

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Found formula, can type in google: `y=3.6+0.5*log(1/(0.99*x+0.005)-1)` That almost resembles curve shape.. probably can use it for model.

Comment: That does not include the dual-slope effects (that causes memory effects)